# Why and how someArray[5] works in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c

I thought the new notation works like this:

someArray[5] turns into

someArray[5] will actually turn into [someArray objectAtIndexedSubscript:5]

However, in NSArray.h and NSOrderedSet.h I saw this:

```
- (id)objectAtIndexedSubscript:(NSUInteger)idx NS_AVAILABLE(10_8, 6_0);
```

So, objectAtIndexedSubscript is only available for IOS6.

I experimented making this simple code:

```
NSArray * someArray =@[@"hello",@"World",@"World"];
NSOrderedSet * someOS = [NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray:someArray];
PO(someArray);
PO(someOS);
PO(someArray[0]);
PO(someOS[0]); //Exception thrown here
```

The code break at someOS[0]

```
-[__NSOrderedSetI objectAtIndexedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8b1fac0
```

in BOTH NSArray and NSOrderedSet, there is a text NS_AVAILABLE(10_8, 6_0);

Yet it doesn't break on NSArray yet break on NSOrderedSet. Why?

Bonus: How do I make it work for NSOrderedSet too with category (need to check that it's not already defined)

Comment: What is your PO()? I have not gotten any exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a better answer!

This code will dynamically patch `NSOrderedSet` for versions of iOS that don't support `-objectAtIndexedSubscript:`.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <objc/runtime.h>

id PatchedObjectAtIndexedSubscript(id self_, SEL cmd_, NSUInteger index)
{
    return [self_ objectAtIndex:index];
}

void PatchedSetObjectAtIndexedSubscript(id self_, SEL cmd_, id object, NSUInteger index)
{
    return [self_ replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:object];
}

void SIPatchNSOrderedSet()
{
    char types[6];

    if (!class_getInstanceMethod([NSOrderedSet class], @selector(objectAtIndexedSubscript:))) {
        sprintf(types, "@@:%s", @encode(NSUInteger));
        class_addMethod([NSOrderedSet class],
                        @selector(objectAtIndexedSubscript:),
                        (IMP)PatchedObjectAtIndexedSubscript,
                        types);
    }

    if (!class_getInstanceMethod([NSMutableOrderedSet class], @selector(setObject:atIndexedSubscript:))) {
        sprintf(types, "v@:@%s", @encode(NSUInteger));
        class_addMethod([NSMutableOrderedSet class],
                        @selector(setObject:atIndexedSubscript:),
                        (IMP)PatchedSetObjectAtIndexedSubscript,
                        types);
    }
}
```

At the start of your application (`-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` maybe) call `SIPatchNSOrderedSet()`.

Comment: WOW. Just Wow. So we can't just make normal category can we?

Comment: v@:@%s why not v@:@s? Why the % before s? Not listed here https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtTypeEncodings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008048-CH100

Comment: @JimThio It's not a normal category because I don't want to override the real implementation in iOS 6, so I conditionally override it when the method is not available.

Comment: @JimThio There is no listed encoding for NSUInteger in the doc, so I use `@encode(NSUInteger)` to get the encoding on the fly. `%s` is `sprintf`'s way of inserting the actual encoding.

Answer (score 3):

In looking into this a little deeper and it looks like it NSOrderSet only has -objectAtIndexedSubscript: in iOS 6, but NSArray has -objectAtIndexedSubscript: in both iOS 5 and iOS 6.

My testing has shown the following.

```
- (void)testNSOrderedSetObjectAtIndexedSubscript
{
    NSString *systemVersion = [UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion;
    NSString *message = @"NSOrderedSet for %@ does not respond to -objectAtIndexedSubscript:";

    NSOrderedSet *orderedSet = [NSOrderedSet orderedSet];
    STAssertTrue([orderedSet respondsToSelector:@selector(objectAtIndexedSubscript:)], message, systemVersion);
}

- (void)testNSArrayObjectAtIndexedSubscript
{
    NSString *systemVersion = [UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion;
    NSString *message = @"NSArray for %@ does not respond to -objectAtIndexedSubscript:";

    NSArray *array = [NSArray array];
    STAssertTrue([array respondsToSelector:@selector(objectAtIndexedSubscript:)], message, systemVersion);
}
```

iOS 5.0 Simulator

```
Test Case '-[SIObjectTests testNSArrayObjectAtIndexedSubscript]' started.
Test Case '-[SIObjectTests testNSArrayObjectAtIndexedSubscript]' passed (0.000 seconds).
Test Case '-[SIObjectTests testNSOrderedSetObjectAtIndexedSubscript]' started.
/Users/jthomas/workspaces/si-catalog-order-ios/SICatalogOrderTests/SIObjectTests.m:20: error: -[SIObjectTests testNSOrderedSetObjectAtIndexedSubscript] : "[orderedSet respondsToSelector:@selector(objectAtIndexedSubscript:)]" should be true. NSOrderedSet for 5.0 does not respond to -objectAtIndexedSubscript:
Test Case '-[SIObjectTests testNSOrderedSetObjectAtIndexedSubscript]' failed (0.000 seconds).
```

iOS 6.0 Simulator

```
Test Case '-[SIObjectTests testNSArrayObjectAtIndexedSubscript]' started.
Test Case '-[SIObjectTests testNSArrayObjectAtIndexedSubscript]' passed (0.000 seconds).
Test Case '-[SIObjectTests testNSOrderedSetObjectAtIndexedSubscript]' started.
Test Case '-[SIObjectTests testNSOrderedSetObjectAtIndexedSubscript]' passed (0.000 seconds).
```

Comment: what is stassert true and what's the difference between that and others?

Comment: @JimThio `STAssert*` functions are a part of OCUnit.

Comment: And why not just use normal NSAssert?

Comment: Because the code is for a couple of [Unit Tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing). [Unit Tests](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/07/i-pity-the-fool-who-doesnt-write-unit-tests.html) are a great way to track issues like this.

Answer (score 0):

Jeffry answer is awesome and provide insight on how declaring your selector work.

For alternative, I simply do this:

```
self.businessDetailed.Phones.array[0];
```

Then I'll tell my future grandchildren to change that to

```
self.businessDetailed.Phones[0];
```

when iPhone 15 hit the shelf.

Much less work than Jeffry's solution at the cost of slightly increased marginal costs along the way.